# How to convert a phone number to that contacts name in TextView on Android?

Tags: android, regex, replace, textview, phone-number

We would like to automatically replace phone numbers within text (TextView) with their corresponding contact names.

Is there a library or code snippet that already does this? Else my naive approach would be to:

- get phone numbers in the text (via a regex, maybe the one used for autolink phone)
- query for contact that has this number (for each number found)
- if found, replace with the corresponding name of the contact

(suggestion for query from @Skynet)

This is currently beeing discussed in a [feature request for TextSecure](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure/issues/2602) but could be useful for other android apps as well.

Comment: Are you fetching these numbers/names from Contacts? If so you dont need to build a regex, just a where clause in your query would do the magic for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to take the list of all contacts. You can get contact name from a phone number. Use this method:

```
public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[]{ PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method to get the contact name using a phone number:**

```
public String getContactName(String number) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(number));
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uri,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER,
                        ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID }, null, null, null);
        String contactName = "";
        if (cur.moveToNext()) {
            int name = cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            contactName = cur.getString(name);

        }
        cur.close();
        return contactName;

    }
```

**Use this when replacing numbers to contact names in your TextView. I hope it works. :)**